# Is there a combinatorial interpretation or bijective proof for this Catalan number identity?

Tags: co.combinatorics, catalan-numbers, bijective-combinatorics

Is there any combinatorial interpretation or bijective proof for this identity
$$2C_n=4{2n \choose n}-{2n+2 \choose n+1}$$
where $C_n$ is the sequence of Catalan numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an obvious bijective proof of the identity
$$ 2 \binom{2n}{n} + 2 \binom{2n}{n + 1} = \binom{2n+2}{n+1}$$
and also a bijective proof of
$$ 2\binom{2n}{n} -  2 \binom{2n}{n+1} =  2C_n,$$
see the paragraph "second proof" [in the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Second_proof). By combining the two, you get a bijective proof of your identity, in the form
$$ 4 \binom{2n}{n} =\binom{2n+2}{n+1} + 2C_n  .$$

Answer (score 1):

In the wikipedia page on Catalan numbers there is the following:

"There are many counting problems in combinatorics whose solution is given by the Catalan numbers. The book Enumerative Combinatorics: Volume 2 by combinatorialist Richard P. Stanley contains a set of exercises which describe 66 different interpretations of the Catalan numbers."

I guess it is a good place to look for an answer.